# Unknown charset accented characters convert to utf8

Tags: perl, utf-8, character-encoding

I have a website that users may enter an accented character search term.
Since users may come from various countries, various OS, the charset accented characters they input may be encoded in windows-1252, iso-8859-1, or even iso-8859-X, windows-125X.

I am using Perl, and my index server is Solr 8, all data in utf8.
I can use decode+encode to convert it if the source charset is known, but how could I convert an unknown accented to utf8?  How could I detect the charset of the source accented characters, in Perl?

```
use utf8;
use Encode;
encode("utf8",decode("cp1252",$input));
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The web page and the form need to specify UTF-8.

Then the browser can accept any script, and will send it to the server as UTF-8.

The form's encoding prevents the browser sending HTML entities like `&#x0103;` for special chars.

Header:

```
Content-type: text/html; charset=UTF-8
```

With perl (empty line for end-of-headers):

```
print "Content-Type: text/html; charset=UTF-8\n\n";
```

HTML content; in HTML 5:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
    <meta charset="UTF-8">
...
<form ... accept-charset="UTF-8"
```

Comment: Thanks a lot! You have saved my life!  form accept-charset="UTF-8" was what I have missed.

Comment: I received an input of "Sch%F6ttl"(ISO-8859-1, Schöttl) from a chrome user,  instead of "Sch%C3%B6ttl"(UTF-8), any idea? I already have charset=utf-8 in Content-type and meta, and accept-charset="UTF-8".

Comment: please ignore it, I think that "Sch%F6ttl" could be sent from his own direct link but not submitted through my search form.

Comment: Note: You should in any case accept that you may get wrong encoding. Many web spiders (but possibly some browsers, maybe just with copy-paste) could ignore your recommendations.

Comment: A bit late, but you are right: client side error. One could verify a `byte[]` received from translating %XX and then fall back when it is no UTF-8 to Windows-1252, aka MS Latin-1, used by browsers instead of ISO-8859-1. (Even a Mac browser will interprete ISO-8859-1 as such, and since HTML 5 that is specified.) ISO-8859-1 is the HTTP default, and might have been erroneously used. Violating UTF-8 conformity can be tested easily.